# How to run servlet Java on Tomcat server via Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, backend

I created a test application with two files for educational purposes: `mypage.jsp` and `mypage2.jsp`. At the same time, the `comLogin` servlet class was created. The bottom line is that on a local server, a user visits the site, enters his name (say, Andrey) and receives a page with a greeting: `Hello Andrew`.

The server is starting. However, when I try to open a website with two pages via `Run As`, I get a system freeze and an error:

> Loading descriptor for MyWeb has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during "Loading descriptor for MyWeb"

The screenshot shows that the server is running. The screen also demonstrates the web download descriptor `web.xml`: it is in the project structure, although for some reason with a red cross (see the `Project Explorer` window on the left). What's the trouble then?

[image]

Comment: What does your Problems view show? What versions of everything are involved?

Comment: @nitind, Eclipse Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0), Tomcat 8.0, jdk-13.0.2

Comment: @nitind, I rebooted the computer. And here's the thing: Eclipse still freezes, declaring that it `Does not respond`, but at the same time typing `localhost8080/MyWeb` in the address bar, I got the desired result. But this is at the cost of a hung program (as it was the day before)

Comment: When Eclipse started working again, I received a notification: The selection did not contain any resources that can run on a server

Comment: Your Eclipse release is a year old. Update it. Perhaps this problem has been addressed since then.